# Apache camel email not being sent using mail component

Tags: apache, apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

Hi I am trying to write small route which reads from file and sends the body of file as mail to destination

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--

    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.

-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>A Camel Route</name>
  <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

  <properties>
    <camel-version>2.16.0</camel-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
      <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
      <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-mail</artifactId>
    <version>${camel-version}</version>
    <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- allows the route to be ran via 'mvn camel:run' -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is my camel-context

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->

<!-- Configures the Camel Context-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <package>com.test</package>
    <!-- here is a sample which processes the input files
         (leaving them in place - see the 'noop' flag)
         then performs content based routing on the message
         using XPath -->
    <route>
      <from uri="file:src/data?noop=true"/>
      <choice>
        <when>
          <xpath>/person/city = 'London'</xpath>
          <to uri="file:target/messages/uk"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
          <to uri="file:target/messages/others"/>
        </otherwise>
      </choice>
    </route>
   <route>
      <from uri="file:src/data/email?noop=true"/>
      <setHeader headerName="subject">
        <constant>the test mail</constant>
      </setHeader>
      <log message="${body}"/>
      <to uri="smtps://smtp.google.com?username=sam89420@gmail.com&amp;password=MYPASSWORD&amp;to=suryawanshiabhinav89@gmail.com"/>
    </route> 
 </camelContext>

</beans>
```

Even though my route runs successfully when i do mvn camel:run but still its not sending message to my another inbox or its not even printing any log message.

I am completely new to camel any help is appreciated